# leaflet.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

i develop example web page that view open street map  and read data from sql server database by Json (javascript)

and let me this error
**leaflet.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null**  
the function return data successfully from database

  **Model file**
here return data by json

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetMap()
    {
        var data1 = (from p in db.Map
                     select new
                     {
                         Name = p.Name,
                         Latitude = p.Latitude,
                         Logitude = p.Logitude,
                         Location = p.Location,
                         Description = p.Description,
                         Id = p.Id
                     }).ToList().Select(res => new Map
                {
                    Name = res.Name,
                    Latitude = res.Latitude,
                    Logitude = res.Logitude,
                    Location = res.Location,
                    Description = res.Description,
                    Id = res.Id


                });
        return Json(data1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**View file** 
here get data from json function  and get data successfully

```
 <body>
<div id="mapid" style="height:600px"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([31.291340, 34.244190], 13);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);




        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Maps/GetMap',
            success: function (data) {
                //var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                var result = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

                    var popup =
                        '<b>Name:</b> ' + data[i].Name
                        +
                     '<br/><b>Latitude:</b> ' + data[i].Latitude +
                       '<br/><b>Longitude:</b> ' + data[i].Logitude +
                    '<br/><b>Location:</b> ' + data[i].Location
                    ;

                    alert(data[i].Name + " " + data[i].Latitude + " / " + data[i].Logitude + " / " + data[i].Location);
                    L.marker(data[i].Logitude,  [data[i].Latitude])

                        .bindPopup(popup)
                       .addTo(map); 

                }

            },
            error: function (xhr) {

                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Error has occurred..");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `var data1 = (from p in db.Map ...).ToList()` => materialize the query contents as `IEnumerable` first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a linq query and those are [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/deferred-execution-example) which means it only gets executed when we are just going to consume it, so you are just passing the `IQueryable` object to `JSON` method and the time it returns back it is not materialized with result.

You need to materialize the result using `ToList()` method when passing to `JSON` method.

Just change your last line to:

```
return Json(data1.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Now the **EF** will execute the query on the database server and will fetch the result and populate in the `List<T>` object.

Hope it helps!